# How to warp or project a point cloud (semi-landmarks) from a template onto a target object in python?

Tags: mesh, projection, point-clouds, affinetransform

For a better understanding see the next figure. [left: template, right: target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKvq9.jpg)

Given are a template point cloud and a target point cloud. The template point cloud has initially four (red) fixed points (landmarks) and some (in this case 9) other (black) points, whereas the target point cloud has initially just four (red) fixed points (landmarks). Now I want to warp/project the template onto the target with the red points as references. So at the end the red dots from the template should align with the red dots from the target and the black dots from the template should be warped/projected onto the target cloud. (In R this warping process is possible with the Edgewarp 3D package/function.)

I have tried many python packages but none of them could generate my requirements. I have also tried to solve this problem using a mesh on the template but could not find a way out.

Comment: (Sorry, can't help you with your question, but am curios which scanner or camera you used to produce such a clear, "high definition", focused scan of your drawing?)